# Using json response in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use one object from the many provided in my json request.

Trying to obtain only the country name from the data that is given.

```
$location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 echo $location;
```

The above code gives me the following string:

```
{"ip":"x.xx.xx.x","country_code":"FR","country_name":"France","region_code":"A2","region_name":"Bretagne","city":"Brest","zipcode":"","latitude":xxxx,"longitude":xxxx,"metro_code":"","area_code":""}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try ```json_decode()```

Comment: Have a look at any if these questions: [`[php] parse json`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+parse+json).

Comment: thank you for your help, down votes on reputation kinda sucks, asking a simple question and had already done my research, found no previous questions that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = json_decode($location);
echo $a->country_name;
```

You might also want to have a look on this. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Look for manual [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
 $tmp = json_decode($location);
    echo $tmp->country_code
```